# C# WPF 3D models

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

For a project I have to use WPF and C# to show some 3D things, but these have to involve reflection of light on a plane, animations, transparency materials, ....

Is there an relative good documented dll I could use to accomplish these things?

I tried doing it wit helixtoolkit, but there the transparancy isn't working as wanted and I can't find any documantation on how to animate things.

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with the transparency? Maybe share some code.

Comment: I have a plane with a transparant material (exported to obj form 3ds max) and every object behind that plan can't be seen. but if you rotate the camera they are there. this is porobably because the renderer thinks he should render the objects that arn't visible, but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: It's because the transparent object is renderer before the opaque one behind it. It's a quite common problem in 3D. Take a look at the Transparency demo from the Helix Framework to know how to sort the transparent objects and render them after opaque ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object supports transparent materials then just add it to the model group last, I'm pretty sure the order that you add them is the order that they render in.